# How to unblock (by spring app) my postgresql db?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I have a spring boot app that uses a postgresql db. When started I can't change data on that db with a db viewer or other tasks that will use the db too.

My initial plan is to run my spring app while I run selenium tests. But I want to connect to the db  before every test, so I can reset the db (remove/create schemata and tables) and create some initial data.

The problem is, the tests starts, but they wait on the first statement execution.

I have no clue what I could do. The max connections are -1.

Comment: I guess it wasn't a good idea to remove the schemata/tables. But it works when I only clear the tables. That remove schemata requests block the db - also for other requests like delete from table. -> restart os.